# Bind data to UltraGird on each row expand

Tags: infragistics, hierarchical-data, ultrawingrid

please tell me how to get and bind data to UltraGrid dynamically on each BeforeRowExpanded event. i have large amount of data which i have to show on each row expanded event. please tell me any useful article/link.

this data is in hierarchical form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mike Saltzman, you will run into difficulty dynamically binding child data:
http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/37514/218323.aspx.

Comment: I would like to know more about the nature of this data. Are the expanded rows child data? Could this be done in ADO.NET, allowing you to create a schema?